# How do I change the color of the surface where the collided object overlaps in unity?

Tags: unity, 3d, shaders

How do I change the color of the surface where the collided object overlaps in unity?

[image: example]
Let's take the board of directors as an example.
I want to change the color of the surface superimposed on the sphere like in the photo.
The reason to change the surface is to change the color of the surface or texture because the object is not separate, but one.

i am the first
I tried to use the phsics.shpere cast.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html

However, shperecast only informs the collision point and the object that collided with, so it does not know any vertices, and first the collision point texture.coord is returned..

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html
Those vertices are useless as they return one vertex per object, not every surface they hit.

I'm trying to create a mesh myself using contacts to use it to hit the collider of a sphere.
I don't think this method is the right way either, but is there a better way?
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-contacts.html

current use way

```
   private void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
    {
        SufraceMehs = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);

        ContactPoint[] contacts=collision.contacts;
        int numContacts = collision.GetContacts(contacts);

        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        Vector3[] contactpos=new Vector3[contacts.Length]; 
        for(int i=0; i< contacts.Length; i++)
        {
            contactpos[i] = contacts[i].point;
        }
        Debug.Log(contactpos.Length);
        mesh.vertices = contactpos;
        SufraceMehs.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;

        //mesh.vertices = contactpos;
        //mesh.triangles= c

    }
```

It would be nice to be able to change or import the color of overlapping parts like this.

Does this work require a shader?
i found this
https://forum.unity.com/threads/highlight-intersection-shader.731177/
but it work only opaque not  transparent
[image]

Comment: Can you visualize for us what you want the changed colour to look like? Try painting over a screenshot in an image editing program to give us a preview of what it should look like.

Comment: Easiest and most performant way to do this is with a shader.

Comment: @DMGregory i edit question thank you

Comment: Do I correctly understand that you want to draw a red line along the curve of intersection?

Comment: @DMGregory  The overlapping part should change color to red. Drawing a line doesn't really matter.
While searching, I found something similar to what I'm talking about, but it doesn't work. Hope it helps.